# Define/design these related Postgres tables in my Prisma schema

Tags: database, postgresql, design-patterns, database-design, prisma

My application using Prisma has users who can create many projects. These projects are akin to text documents, but with some additional attributes that assist with organization.

These projects will always be "owned" by the user who originally created them, and that user has control over administering access, whether that be view, comment or even edit, to other users. Users who have access to another user's project(s) are considered "collaborators" in the application.

In the current application architecture, a user can create and own many collaborators, and the creating user has full control over which of their projects a collaborator can access and to what degree--view, comment, edit.

A user in the application carries the regular user-related metadata, like name and email. A project in the application carries project-related data, like the name of the project and other attributes.

I created a table that stores a user's collaborators (users) in order to display a list of those collaborators on a page where a user can perform CRUD actions for collaborators.

In order to show a user the projects they're associated with on the home page, I created another table that references a project and its related user and adds a role, which defines whether that user is the owner or a collaborator.

This allows me to display the projects that a user has access to on the home page of the application, whether the user created the project or is merely a collaborator.

So when a user logs in and goes to their home page, what they see is a full list of projects where they're either the owner or just a collaborator.

For projects in the list where the user is the owner I need to display a list of avatars that represent that project's collaborators.

Why should I do one of

- Create another table that defines the relationship/association from project to collaborator?
- Rethink my schema/database design in a larger way?

```
model User {
  id                   String                   @id @default(cuid())
  name                 String?
  email                String?                  @unique
  emailVerified        DateTime?
  image                String?
  accounts             Account[]
  sessions             Session[]
  collaborator         UserCollaborator[]       @relation("Collaborator")
  userCollaborators    UserCollaborator[]       @relation("UserCollaborators")
  collabInviteReceived UserCollaboratorInvite[] @relation("InviteReceived")
  collabInviteSent     UserCollaboratorInvite[] @relation("InviteSent")
  userProjects         UserProject[]
}

model Project {
  id           String        @id @default(cuid())
  name         String?
  createdAt    DateTime      @default(now())
  updatedAt    DateTime      @updatedAt
  things       Thing[]
  userProjects UserProject[]
}

model UserProject {
  projectId                String
  roleId                   Int
  userId                   String
  createdAt                DateTime                  @default(now())
  updatedAt                DateTime                  @updatedAt
  project                  Project                   @relation(fields: [projectId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  role                     Role                      @relation(fields: [roleId], references: [id])
  user                     User                      @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userCollaboratorProjects UserCollaboratorProject[]

  @@id([userId, projectId])
}

model UserCollaborator {
  ownerId                  String
  collaboratorId           String
  roleId                   Int
  status                   CollaboratorStatusEnum
  // this is the user who is the collaborator
  collaborator             User                      @relation("Collaborator", fields: [collaboratorId], references: [id])
  // this is the user who created the collaborator
  owner                    User                      @relation("UserCollaborators", fields: [ownerId], references: [id])
  role                     Role                      @relation(fields: [roleId], references: [id])
  userCollaboratorProjects UserCollaboratorProject[]

  @@id([ownerId, collaboratorId])
}

model UserCollaboratorProject {
  userProjectProjectId           String
  userProjectUserId              String
  userCollaboratorOwnerId        String
  userCollaboratorCollaboratorId String
  userCollaborator               UserCollaborator @relation(fields: [userCollaboratorOwnerId, userCollaboratorCollaboratorId], references: [ownerId, collaboratorId], onDelete: Cascade)
  userProject                    UserProject      @relation(fields: [userProjectUserId, userProjectProjectId], references: [userId, projectId], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@id([userProjectUserId, userProjectProjectId, userCollaboratorOwnerId, userCollaboratorCollaboratorId])
}
```

Comment: 1) Could you describe the problem *without* referencing your existing schema? That will make it easier to understand. For example, "When a collaborator logs in and goes to their projects page, what they see is a list of UserProject records" What are UserProject records representing? Projects they own? Projects they have a role in? What makes a user a collaborator? When is UserProject used vs UserCollaborator? 2) I notice UserCollaborator has no reference to User, that seems odd. But it does reference itself, that also seems odd.

Comment: Does reading about [associative entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) and [fourth normal form](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_normal_form) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Comment: [Why is asking a question on "best practice" a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353/266284) 
[Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461) Yes or no questions are seldom useful & (since they ask for a yes or a no) are seldom asking for what the asker actually wants answered.  It is unhelpful & unclear to ask 'A or B' when A & B are not mutually exclusive and/or not the only options. (And you may think they are when they are not.) Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts.

Comment: You say 'create' &  'own' a collaborator but what you seem to be trying to say is that a user names them/users in order to assign them, ie to be associated in a certain way, ie what they create & own are (ER) association instances/tuples ie (ER) relationships. Using the words you do & talking about the entities as if they were the relationships is unclear/confusing. Just say that a user can designate other users as collaborators, or that a user can cause other users to be so associated with themself. A collaborator is a user who participates in a certain association.--If that's what you mean.

Comment: @philipxy -- You'll have to forgive my ignorance and lack of vocabulary. Yes, a user can give another user in the system access to their data (project(s)) as a "collaborator", as its referred to in the application.

Comment: Best is to ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question about where & how you are 1st stuck/unsure, with the published information modelling & DB design method you are following. If you don't give (or have!) this context then an answer is (re)writing such a reference with bespoke tutorial with no idea what you do or don't understand or misunderstand, or which method it is. Also one must pin down & write many clear, concise & precise phrasings of one's question/problem/goal to (re)search reasonably. [ask] [Help] Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue in your design is making the project owner distinct from a project collaborator. These overlap. For example, when you want to list all projects a user is participating in.

You can solve this by defining a new entity which I'll call "Project Participator". This is everyone participating in the project: owners, admins, viewers, editors, etc. And that is what you want to list.

---

Another issue is making collaborators "owned" by the user which owns the project. This is data duplication. It invites the possibility that the collaborator's owner might not be the project's owner.

Collaborators should instead be "owned" by the project. From there they can find the owner of the project. This eliminates the data duplication, there's no possibility of the collaborator owner being different from the project owner, and it leaves open the possibility of changing the definition of who "owns" the collaborator.

Business rules change, even if you've been promised they have not. The schema should strive to hard code only fundamental relationships. Business rules should be done in data or software. Even if the rules don't change, this makes your design more flexible for additional features.

---

I'm going to propose these entities...

```
User
  id
  name
  email
  ...
  has many ProjectParticipants
  has many Projects through ProjectParticipants

Project
  name
  ...
  has many ProjectParticipants
  has many Users through ProjectParticipants

ProjectRoles
  id
  name

ProjectParticipant
  belongs to a User
  belongs to a Project
  has many ProjectRoles
```

Every User involved with a Project is a ProjectParticipant.

Every ProjectParticipant has one or more ProjectRoles. These would be view, edit, comment, and owner.

You can list all of a User's Projects by joining with ProjectParticipants.

When a User creates a Project you'd make them a ProjectParticipant with the owner role.

You can define a "collaborator" as a ProjectParticipant who does not have the owner role.

What the roles do is not defined in the schema, it is defined in software. In your case you'd only allow ProjectParticipants with the ProjectRole of "owner" in that Project to make changes to other ProjectParticipants. You can change this later to allow, for example, "admin" to make changes to ProjectParticipants.

ProjectRoles is simply a list of all possible roles. It's going to start as just an id and a words. It could be an enum, but it's better done as a join table. This lets you rename the roles without having to change everyone's data. It makes some queries easier to have a join table, like enumerating every role. It allows roles to become more complicated later by adding rows.

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/YEm8nRB1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have a few clarifying question on things I don't fully understand. By "You can list all of a User's Projects by joining with ProjectParticipants." Do you mean by selecting projects where the project participant equals the user and has the owner role? By saying ProjectRoles is "better done as a join table" do you mean storing each ProjectRole simply as "id" and "name" and then referencing that id on ProjectParticipant? But a Participant can have many roles on a project?

Comment: @deepsun 1) [This demonstration should clarify](https://dbfiddle.uk/YEm8nRB1). You should be able to translate that into your ORM. 2) I've made it so a user can have many roles on a project. This makes roles more granular and explicit. Instead of having to know that the "edit" role can also "view" and "comment", you can be explicit and assign all three roles, or assign roles in any combination. It's ok to skip it and make it so a participant has one role and retrofit it later.

Comment: Ah, demo is very helpful. Last question. In the design you've proposed, to query and select all of the project participants who are participating in projects where the current user's role is "own", would the query run directly on participants or do a join on that table? This query would be used to populate data on a user's "Participant" management page so they could take CRUD actions on users participating in projects where the current user's role is "own" and the users in the query have a role other than "own". Thanks for the detailed explanations! This is very helpful.

Comment: @deepsun "*would the query run directly on participants or do a join on that table?*" Because ProjectParticipant contains very little information itself, anything but simple lookups of participants will involve joins and [relation queries](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-client/queries/relation-queries). Why do you ask?

Comment: Asking to help myself create a mental model for the relationships between these tables, in order to understand how to refactor features like the page that lists "Collaborators". We still need some sort of screen in the application where a user can administer project participants for projects where that user has the "own" role. Think I have a working query for this: "select project_participants where project_participant.user != current_user_email and where at least one of the project_participant.project.project_participants is the current user and the project_participant_role = "own".

Comment: @deepsun The final query in the demo shows how to get all the projects owned a user. Since you're using Prisma, you shouldn't have to write most SQL by hand, but it is useful to understand.

Comment: @deepsun Note that you're going to want to make use of [cascading deletes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44956/good-explanation-of-cascade-on-delete-update-behavior) so when you, for example, delete a project it also automatically deletes every record relating to that project. I did not cover this. [Prisma supports these](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-schema/data-model/relations/referential-actions). That will make the D part of CRUD much easier.

Comment: Okay, right. I saw that query when I first looked at your example but forgot about it. And cascading deletes was already something I had been using. Thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: I understand the most basic aspects of using a relational database, but with best-practice, design-related things like this I'm still fuzzy. Would you say that your proposed changes follow any sort of known/named "patterns" in relational DB design? I want to find some more resources on DB design and was curious. Thanks!

Comment: @deepsun Lots and lots. This is all based on [relational algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) and set theory. More practically there is the [relational model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model) and [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and there are formal "normal forms". These address [referential integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity), [data redundancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_redundancy), and [data integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_integrity).

Comment: @deepsun And from the practical performance side, [Use The Index, Luke](https://use-the-index-luke.com/). For example, you had the Project owner copied into every UserCollaborator row; this creates data redundancy. In my version, there is only one source of truth for who owns a Project, and this must be looked up by joining related tables. Each relationship is declared and constrained as `not null` to ensure the references continue to be valid. For example, `user_id integer not null references users` will not let you delete the referring user (unless you add `on delete cascade`).